# Get my GUI to display?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

What do I need to insert to get my whole GUI to display?
I believe I have everything formatted correctly on my AirlineReservation.java class. I'm just sure of how to actual go about and print the GUI i've created to test it.

```
 package airline;

    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;

    import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
    import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JMenu;
    import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
    import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
    import javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem;
    import javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem;
    import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
    import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JSlider;
    import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

    import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
    import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
    import userInterface.AirlineReservation;



    //Begin AirportMain class
    public class AirportMain {

    //Main Method
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //New instance of Airport
     Airport airport = new Airport(
     "Orlando International Airport", "Orlando", "Florida","MCO");  


        //Create an instance of Airline and Flight for Delta  
        Flight flight = new Flight(1);
        Airline delta = new Airline();
        delta.setAirlineName("Delta Airlines");
        delta.setAirlineHubLocation("ATL");
        delta.setFlight(flight);
        flight.setFlightNumber(98);
        flight.setDestinationLocation("Buffalo, NY");

        //Create an instance of Airline and Flight for United
        Flight flights = new Flight(2);
        Airline united = new Airline();
        united.setAirlineName("United Airlines");
        united.setAirlineHubLocation("MCO");
        united.setFlight(flights);
        flights.setFlightNumber(234);
        flights.setDestinationLocation("Los Angeles, CA");

        //Displays info from Airport/Delta/United in a dialog box
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, airport.toString() + 
        delta.toString() + "\n" +  united.toString());




    }
       AirlineReservation airlineReservation = new AirlineReservation();


     }
```

Here is the code for my GUI

```
package userInterface;

    import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AirlineReservation {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel label;
    private JMenu fileMenu;
    private JMenu formatMenu;
    private JMenu reserveMenu;
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenuItem menuItem1;
    private JMenuItem menuItem2;
    private JMenuItem menuItem3;
    private JMenuItem menuItem4;
    private JMenuItem menuItem5;
    private JRadioButtonMenuItem radioMenuItem1;
    private JRadioButtonMenuItem radioMenuItem2;
    private JCheckBoxMenuItem checkMenuItem1;
    private JCheckBoxMenuItem checkMenuItem2;
    private JSlider slider;
    private JTabbedPane tabPane;


   public AirlineReservation()
    {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void initComponents()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Airline Reservation");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setSize(300, 300);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Now lets create a JMenuBar to add to our JFrame
        // Initializing the JMenuBar
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);


        // Initializing menu items
        menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("Add Airport");
        menuItem2 = new JMenuItem("Add Airline");
        menuItem3 = new JMenuItem("Add Flight");

        // Initializing the JMenu and adding JMenuItems
        fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        fileMenu.setMnemonic('F');
        fileMenu.add(menuItem1);
        fileMenu.add(menuItem2);
        fileMenu.add(menuItem3);


        // Initializing menu items
        menuItem4 = new JMenuItem("Search Flights");
        menuItem5 = new JMenuItem("Make Reservation");

        // Initializing the JMenu and adding JMenuItems
        reserveMenu = new JMenu("Reservation");
        reserveMenu.setMnemonic('R');
        reserveMenu.add(menuItem4);
        reserveMenu.add(menuItem5);



        // Initializing the menu items
        radioMenuItem1 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Times New Roman");
        radioMenuItem2 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Comic Sans");
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(radioMenuItem1);
        group.add(radioMenuItem2);

        checkMenuItem1 = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Bold");
        checkMenuItem2 = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Italics");

        // Initializing the JMenu and adding JMenuItems
        formatMenu = new JMenu("Format");
        formatMenu.setMnemonic('M');
        formatMenu.add(radioMenuItem1);
        formatMenu.add(radioMenuItem2);
        formatMenu.addSeparator();
        formatMenu.add(checkMenuItem1);
        formatMenu.add(checkMenuItem2);



        // Add the menus to the JMenuBar
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(reserveMenu);
        menuBar.add(formatMenu);



        // Add the menubar to the JFrame
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        slider = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 200, 10);
        // sets the value for each major tick spacing
        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(50);
        // makes the tick labels with values visible
        slider.setPaintLabels(true);
        // makes the individual tick marks visible
        //        slider.setPaintTicks(true);
        // This is an event handler
        slider.addChangeListener(
                // This is an anonymous inner class
                new ChangeListener()
                {
                    // This handles the updated value of the slider
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
                    {
                        // sets the text of the label to the actual value on the slide
                        // explicit type casting because setText expects a String
                        // but getValue returns and int
                        label.setText(String.valueOf(slider.getValue()));
                    }
                });


        // initializing the JTabbedPane
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("panel 1");
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

        // adding a label to display the value of the slider
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        panel1.add(label);
        panel1.add(slider);
        panel1.add(label1);

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("panel 2");
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.add(label2);

        tabPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabPane.addTab("Tab One", null, panel1, "First Panel");
        tabPane.addTab("Tab Two", null, panel2, "Second Panel");
        frame.add(tabPane);

    }
 public class FileMenuAction implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getActionCommand() == "Add Airport") {
                System.out.println("Add Airport Clicked");
            } else if (e.getActionCommand() == "Add Airline") {
                System.out.println("Add Airline Clicked");

            } else if (e.getActionCommand() == "Add Flight") {
                System.out.println("Add Flight Clicked");
            }
        }
    }

    public class BookMenuAction implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getActionCommand() == "sjsjsjs") {
                System.out.println("fjfhfhf");
            }
        }
    }

    public class AboutMenuAction implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand() == "About Info")
        { System.out.println("About Application clicked");}}
    }
}
```

Comment: The frame should be made visible AFTER all the components have been added to the GUI.

Comment: How did you test it so far if you can't see it?

Answer (score 3):

Remove this line from the GUI constructor:

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Add this line at the end of the GUI constructor:

```
frame.pack();
```

Add this method to your GUI class:

```
public void showFrame() {
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Remove this line from your main class:

```
AirlineReservation airlineReservation = new AirlineReservation();
```

And add the following to your main method:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        AirlineReservation airlineReservation = new AirlineReservation();
        airlineReservation.showFrame();
    }
});
```

This is basically what is covered by the ["Getting started" part of the Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html). Read it. You should never write such a huge piece of code without testing it after each small step, especially if you're a newbie. These lines above should have been the first lines of the application.

Comment: thanks for the thorough reply! The directions given to me/what I was taught are frustrating. I've been building in the dark. I have swapped everything but the last section of code you suggested gives me a "cannot find symbol" error

Comment: I messed up the last snippet. @osandum has fixed it for me. Thanks. I'll repeat: especially when you're a newbie, you should implement things step by step, with steps as short as possible, and test after each step.

Comment: I see that, lots of documentation to go over in your link, thank you! And thank you @osandum for the assist. I am still getting a ')' error though?

Comment: Fixed the missing perenthesis.

Comment: That did it. Much appreciated sir! I'll be studying up after today.